# iMac 24" as a monitor for windows laptop

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, mac, display

The company I work for are about to give me a windows laptop, a thinkpad x200, so that I can work from home. It will have a displayport for an external monitor via a docking station. I have a 24" iMac, can I use that as the external monitor?

Comment: The short answer is no. I have to buy an external monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they work like that, unless the Mac is capable of DVI in. You may want to use something like [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) to do it virtually.

Comment: as it's a company laptop, I wont be able to install any software on it.